# xPages dataTable right-click context menu

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

Does anybody have an example how to implement xp:dataTable right-click context menu? There are few examples for dataGrid control on Google but not for dataTable/view

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK.. seems there is no standard solution. I'm going to build my own context menu by using css.. Almost done.. Will post my solution later